# How do I select an object without problems?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Whenever I try to select this model, there's always this tiny bit that won't be selected. It's crucial that I get this part or It will not bend the limb correctly. I'm using Ctrl to select the object, but It's not selecting It.

Comment: How over the mouse pointer and Press L it will select the mesh and related mesh

Comment: It selects a whole lot more than I need? Is there any way to reduce It?

Comment: perhaps share your file so that we see why you can't select this edge

Comment: Select all and remove doubles in Edit mode.